# Java Stream - Exception while Accumulating Double values with Collectors.reducing()

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a list of `Author` objects. And I need to generate a `Map<String,Author>` associating a *key*, which consists of concatenated `transId` and `countryCode`, with a *value* representing an aggregated `Author` object.

```
public static class Author {
    String transId;
    String countryCode;
    Double currencyUSD;
    Double exccessAmount;
    
    // constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Consider the following example:

```
Author a1 = new Author("1111111", "US", 1000.00, 50.0);
Author a2 = new Author("1111111", "US", 1000.00, 50.0);
Author a3 = new Author("1111111", "US", 1000.00, 1000.00);
Author a4 = new Author("222222", "US", 1000.00, 1000.00);
Author a5 = new Author("222222", "US", 1000.00, 1000.00);
Author a6 = new Author("3333333", "US", 1000.00, 1000.00);
Author a7 = new Author("444444", "US", 1000.00, 1000.00);
        
List<Author> authors = List.of(
    a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7
);
```

Here there are several objects having same `transId` and `countryCode`, like `a1`, `a2` and `a3`. I want to aggregate them by adding `currencyUSD` values in each group together, and also `exccessAmount` values.

*My code:*

```
public static void prepareList() {

    List<Author> authors = // initializing the list

    Map<String, Author> mapList2 = authors.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            authorObj -> authorObj.getTransId() + "_" + authorObj.getCountryCode(),
            Collectors.reducing(
                new Author("", "", 0D, 0D),
                (x, y) -> { 
                    y.setCurrencyUSD(Double.sum(y.getCurrencyUSD(), x.getCurrencyUSD()));
                    y.setExccessAmount(Double.sum(y.getExccessAmount(), x.getExccessAmount())); 
                    return y; 
                })
            ));
        
}
```

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` in the collector while generating the map. How can I add a *null-check* to my code?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Examples.App.lambda$1(App.java:206) at
java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$reducing$42(Collectors.java:877) at
java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$groupingBy$53(Collectors.java:1136) at
java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169) at
java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) at
java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
```

Comment: It's hard to say. What does your `Author` class look like? You have a 4 argument constructor that you use in your reducing collector, but you're using setters for your other instances. Seems a bit fishy, why not just use the 4 arg constructor for all of your examples. Also, why do you need so many example entries? Can you reduce the number and reproduce the problem?

Comment: Author class is just having variables with setters and Getters Like below

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko removed code and added in Question. What exactly is incorrect inside Collectors.reducing

Comment: Again, `reducing(new Author(0,0),->{` is not correct, arguments of the `BinaryOperator` are missing. Apart from that, with the sample data, your issue is **not** reproducible. The only thing I can say for sure is that in somewhere in your data, there's a `null` value hiding among `exccessAmount` and `currencyUSD`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko How can I add null check.

Answer (score 1):

## Object.requireNonNull

You can use [`Object.requireNonNull(T,String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,java.lang.String)) to validate if your references are `null`. Provided message would help in identifying the culprit. As I've said in the comments, it's hiding somewhere in your data (your **real data**, not the sample one) among `exccessAmount` and `currencyUSD` values.

```
Map<String, Author> autorById = authors.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        authorObj -> authorObj.getTransId() + "_" + authorObj.getCountryCode(),
        Collectors.reducing(
            new Author("", "", 0D, 0D),
            (y, x) -> {
            y.setCurrencyUSD(y.getCurrencyUSD() +  Objects.requireNonNull(x.getCurrencyUSD(),"currencyUSD of is Null" + x));
            y.setExccessAmount(y.getExccessAmount() +  Objects.requireNonNull(x.getExccessAmount(),"exccessAmount of is Null" + x));
            return y;
        }
    )));
```

#### *Note:*

- *This fix only resolves the problem with a* `NullPointerException`, *but the code is still* **BROKEN** - *read further!*
- As *@Holger* has pointed out in the comments, static method `Double.sum()` was introduced with Java 8 to serve as a convenient implementation of the `BinaryOperator` via *method reference* `Double::sum`. In all other cases, plain plus operator `+` is a more suitable tool. Because `a+b` is more straightforward than `Double.sum(a,b)`.

In case if you don't want to treat `null` value of `exccessAmount`, or `currencyUSD` as an abnormal case you can use [`Objects.requireNonNullElse(T,T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse(T,T)) instead. It expects a *default value* as the second argument. But I would not recommend taking this rout, instead you can simply initialize this fields to zero in your class.

## Mutable reduction vs. Immutable reduction

There's another issue, obscured by the exception you're getting. Your code is **broken** due to the way you're performing reduction.

`Collectors.reducing` is meant for immutable reduction, i.e. for folding operation in which every reduction step results in creation of a new immutable object like `Integer`, `BigDecimal`, etc. But you've provided a **mutable** *identity* and performing mutation of this object while folding the stream instead of creating a new one.

As the result of that, the *identity* object would be created only **once** per thread. This single instance `Author` would be used for accumulation and reference to it end up in each and every value. Hence, the result would be incorrect.

Also have a look at the Stream API documentation [Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) and [MutableReduction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction). Here's a quote explaining how `Stream.reduce()` works (the mechanism behind `Collectors.reducing()` is the same):

> The **accumulator function** takes a partial result and the next element, and produces a **new partial result**.

But your accumulator doesn't create a new object while producing a partial result. That's the problem. And here's the proof, a map produced with your sample data (all the values are identical because it's literally the same object):

```
Author(transId=, countryCode=, currencyUSD=7000.0, exccessAmount=5100.0)
Author(transId=, countryCode=, currencyUSD=7000.0, exccessAmount=5100.0)
Author(transId=, countryCode=, currencyUSD=7000.0, exccessAmount=5100.0)
Author(transId=, countryCode=, currencyUSD=7000.0, exccessAmount=5100.0)
Author(transId=, countryCode=, currencyUSD=7000.0, exccessAmount=5100.0)
```

To address this issue, you need either:

- generate a new `Author` while accumulating values with `Collectors.reducing` (which would be wasteful since object creation has a cost and your objects are mutable);
- use **mutable reduction**.

Here's an example how to implement *mutable reduction* using a custom collector created via [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)):

```
Map<String, Author> autorById = authors.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        authorObj -> authorObj.getTransId() + "_" + authorObj.getCountryCode(),
        Collector.of(
            () -> new Author("", "", 0D, 0D),
            (Author result, Author next) -> {
                result.setCurrencyUSD(result.getCurrencyUSD() + Objects.requireNonNull(next.getCurrencyUSD(), "currencyUSD of is Null" + next)));
                result.setExccessAmount(result.getExccessAmount() + Objects.requireNonNull(next.getExccessAmount(), "exccessAmount of is Null" + next)));
            },
            (left, right) -> {
                left.setCurrencyUSD(left.getCurrencyUSD() + right.getCurrencyUSD()));
                left.setExccessAmount(left.getExccessAmount() + right.getExccessAmount()));
                return left;
            })
    ));
```

This code can be simplified by extracting the logic from the *accumulator* and *combiner* into a method `merge()` that would reside in the `Author` class, so that inside the *collector* there would be only a couple of method references.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
    * Returns a {@code Collector} which performs a reduction of its
    * input elements under a specified {@code BinaryOperator} using the
    * provided identity.
    *
    * @apiNote
    * The {@code reducing()} collectors are most useful when used in a
    * multi-level reduction, downstream of {@code groupingBy} or
    * {@code partitioningBy}.  To perform a simple reduction on a stream,
    * use {@link Stream#reduce(Object, BinaryOperator)}} instead.
    *
    * @param <T> element type for the input and output of the reduction
    * @param identity the identity value for the reduction (also, the value
    *                 that is returned when there are no input elements)
    * @param op a {@code BinaryOperator<T>} used to reduce the input elements
    * @return a {@code Collector} which implements the reduction operation
    *
    * @see #reducing(BinaryOperator)
    * @see #reducing(Object, Function, BinaryOperator)
    */
```

I copied the comments on the `reducing` method. The first param you input is a `new Author()`. This `new Author` will be used on the first time `reducing`, which means your lambda function `(x,y)->{...}` will be applied with `(x=new Author(),y=a1)`. The `x` has only null fields, so you could try to set a default value, or null check to avoid a `NullPointerException`.